# Decrypting HTTP Response for Exoplayer

Tags: android, encryption, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

Okay, I want to decrypt http response that receives in exoplayer. Not all responses, just one http response with some specific header tag!

In detail: I can give the HLS playlist link to Exoplayer, so its featches the encrypted ts files and will start playing. But the decryption key which exo player featches can be seen with any network analysis tool like fiddler. So i would like to pass an encrypted decryption key from server to app, which can be decrypted just before Exoplayer and pass it to expo player. After googling, i came to know about HttpDataSource, but i dont have a deeper understanding of it. So please someone help me out here.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM Nope.. i didn't.